# SQL Server constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I want to delete the path if status is equal to 'y'. but it is not working.

```
create table example
(
    [status] varchar(1) not null check([status] in ('y', 'n')),
    [path] varchar(70) not null  
    if([status] == 'y') {  
        [path] == null;
    }
)
```

Comment: Is it a SELECT ? Can you give us the full statement ?

Comment: Can you give us the full error message, too?

Comment: no it is not a select it is the create table

Comment: You mean you want to delete whatever value is in `path` if the `status` is updated to `'y'`? I wouldn't go there. Instead, I would either use a computed column or use `case` in the select statement. Loosing data is kind of the opposite of what a database should do.

Comment: but it is necessary, it must be deleted

Comment: Besides what Zohar Peled said, if you define [path] as not null, do you really want to say in the next line that [path] is null? It can be null or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, I would not set the existing value to `null`. Instead, a computed column seems like a better option to me. 
Also, `varchar(1)` is the second worst data type you can choose (`nvarchar(1)` is even worst).  First, if you know you only ever going to have a fixed length string, use `char` or `nchar`. Second, if it's only to specify `y` or `n`, You better simply use `bit`, what only holds values of 0 or 1.

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    [status] bit not null, -- 0 for `n`, 1 for `y`
    [originalPath] varchar(70) not null, -- keeps the original value. Think write only.
    [path] as (case when status = 1 then 
                   null 
               else 
                   originalPath 
               end) -- computed column to use in select statements. This is read only.
)
```